# 3D BSP rendering for maps made in 2d platform style

Tags: rendering, maps, platformer, binary-space-partitioning

I wish to render a 3D map which is always seen from top, camera is in sky and always looking at earth. Sample of a floor layout:

[image]

I don't think I need complex structures like BSP trees to render them. I mean I can divide the map in grids and render them like done in 2D platform games. I just want to know if this is a good idea and what may go wrong if I don't choose a BSP tree rendering here. Please also mention is any better known rendering techniques are available for such situations.

Comment: The actual question you're asking is: "Is it a good idea to *not* use BSP tree?"? Yes, it's a good idea not to use them if you have something what works better for you. There are lots of ways to render maps (and you're actually asking about *optimizing* the rendering, you can use BSP trees with multiple rendering strategies), not using one or another can be a good idea or bad idea, depending on a number of factors.

Answer (score 1):

From your sample image, it looks like the projection you're using is orthographic. If that's the case you can pre-render the whole map to an image/set of images( depending on your resolution) . Then in your game you can just crop to the portion of the image that would be visible from the camera and paint the image in the background.

Of course, this will only work if the characters in the scene are always painted on top of your floor plan.